# How to specify the position of a voice channel in the list of channels? discord.py

Tags: python, api, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a voice channel on my discord server using a bot, but I need it in a specific position on the list of channels. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for [VoiceChannel.edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.edit).

You can pass `position={index}` to move the channel to an arbitrary position in your channellist.

Comment: In case you find more specific questions, please post code snippets and/or a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants a snippet

```
# creates the category at the top of the server channels
category_text = 'ex category'
category = await ctx.guild.create_category(category_text, position=0)
# creates the channel
channel_total_members = await ctx.guild.create_text_channel('lmao1')
# edit other parameters of the channel such as name, position or the category that is in
await channel_total_members.edit(name="test1", position=0, category=category)
```